# new column in Pandas python based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am quite new to pandas, hence, I need help from you experts out there!

I'm quite confusing on concatenation the data from a multiple row.

```
#copy selected row and column. Set specific column into a appropriate data type
filep2 = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/syafiq/Downloads/RoutingPractice01/my_raw.csv')
#set column date/time and idd datatype
filep2['Received Date/Time']= filep2['Received Date/Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
filep2['IDD']=filep2['IDD'].astype(str)
#select the specific column
df = pd.DataFrame(filep2, columns=['Account User Name','Sender','Body','IDD','Received Date/Time'])
df2= df.loc[df['IDD'].notnull(),['Account User Name','Sender','Body','IDD','Received Date/Time']]
df = pd.DataFrame(df2)
#create new column as Concat
concat =''
df['Concat']=concat
print(df2)
```

My csv file "my_raw.csv" contains thousands thousands of row with 15 columns.

While the body column content a message. The IDD column contain an assign key to that specific body message.

For example in my csv file, as follows;

```
Sender          Body                      UDH              Date/Time
ABC     Hello                          CD30010101       01/01/20 1:57
ABC     John                           CD30010102       01/01/20 1:58
XYZ     Please Wait for your turn      3300020201       01/01/20 17:57
XYZ     While waiting for our staff    3300020202       01/01/20 17:58
XYZ     To Complete his task           3300020203       01/01/20 17:59
ABC     Your Parcel is Here            1100DCB001       03/01/20 11:57
```

As you can see above, I want to concatenate the body into a single line and copy into a new column (which I already name it as a Concat). While selecting the date of the last the message were received.

For an example: ABC with UDH CD30010101 and CD30010102, the body message need to group together and copy it into a new column. While copy the last date/time received which is 01/01/20 1:58 into a new column as well.

Desired Output:

```
                 Concat                                 Date/Time 
(ROW 1) Hello John                                    01/01/20 1:58
(ROW 2) Please wait for your turn while waiting
        for our staff to complete his task            01/01/20 17:59
```

I've been trying it for days, still no dice, keep hitting the brick wall.

Need your guidance and expertise!!

Appreciate and thank you very much!

Comment: can you kindly show you need your desired output

Comment: But why CD30010101 and CD30010102 needs to group together? They are not the same ID. Unless you have a tolerance of X?

Comment: @jeril As requested, kindly refer the updated post shared. Thanks

Comment: @HenryYik The CD30010101 and CD30010102 represent the ID of that message. The body has limit of characters, hence it'll split when it were sent to the receiver. The UDH is refer as the identity/key of that particular body message from the same sender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

**Edited based on your file actual column name and desired column name:**

I just realize you want to group them by `Sender` as well as `UHG` that starts with the same characters (how many? You didn't specify, so I just stick to 5 chars in my example below).

The following should achieve what you require:

```
def concat_series_to_string(series):
    return ' '.join(series)

df['Received Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Received Date/Time'])

# Update according to your actual session identification method.
df['UDH_session'] = df['UDH'].str[:5] 

df_concat = df\
    .groupby(['Sender','UDH_session'])\
    .agg({'Body':[concat_series_to_string],'Received Date/Time':['last']})\

df_concat.columns = ['Concat','Received Date/Time (last)']
df_concat = df_concat.sort_values('Received Date/Time (last)')
```

which gives you:
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was busy on handling something, will try and vote your answer as soon I get my hand on the codes. Referring to your question above, yes, the UDH is unique based on the last 5 digits. Appreciate your feedback and help! Many Thanks!

Comment: sorry for asking this question, may I know the 'concat_series_to_string' do? because when I try to run it, it gave me an error of "undefined name concat_series_to_string". Thanks for the warm welcome as well!

Comment: It is just a helper function that does `' '.join(series)`

Comment: Hi @Toukenzie sorry again, it gave me an error of It gave me an error of ValueError: No axis named Date/Time for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> I believe it is the last row of the code above

Comment: Is your input dataframe the same as what u specified? I didn't face any errors.

Comment: Ahh sorry about this, in the csv file it is Received Date/Time, I want to create a new column which will be Received Date/Time (last). Would mind tell me on which should I make a amend on the codes?

Comment: @SyafiqRosli i updated my answer, hopefully it is what you want!

Comment: Hi @toukenize, following your given codes, I manage to concat the body only with the similar UDH. For example, UDH ABC0050101 body does not concat with UDH ABC0050102 and ABC0050103

Comment: Please check your code and data (are they spaces in the string) because the `groupby` operation is on the first 5 characters of UDH and Sender, and it worked fine on the sample you provided.

Comment: I already .str.strip() the UDH column. I noticed you mentioned first 5 characters of UDH, it should have been the last 5 of character of UDH, hence I should write it as df['UDH'].str[-5:].

Comment: I have no idea what you implemented. `groupby` works by grouping the same thing together, it will group nothing if you change it to `df['UDH'].str[-5:]` because the last 5 characters are different.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(<csv file name>)
df_concat = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Concat', 'Date/Time'])
df_concat['Concat'] = df.groupby('Sender')['Body'].apply(' '.join)
df_concat['Date/Time'] = df.groupby('Sender')['Date/Time'].last()
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you only want to (almost) concat consecutive lines with same sender. In fact the required operation is probably more a `' '.join` to ensure a space between consecutive lines.

You can identify groups on consecutive lines with same sender with `(df['Sender'] != df['Sender'].shift()).cumsum()`.

In the end, you can do:

```
resul = df.groupby((df['Sender'] != df['Sender'].shift()).cumsum()
                    ).agg({'Sender': 'first', 'Body': ' '.join, 'Date/Time': max}
                         ).rename_axis(None)
```

It gives:

```
  Sender                                               Body       Date/Time
1    ABC                                         Hello John   01/01/20 1:58
2    XYZ  Please Wait for your turn While waiting for ou...  01/01/20 17:59
3    ABC                                Your Parcel is Here  03/01/20 11:57
```

Comment: Actually I prefer this answer than mine. Though it took awhile for me to figure out the grouping condition `(df['Sender'] != df['Sender'].shift()).cumsum()`

Comment: Hi @Serge Ballesta, appreciate your help! Based from your code given, the unique on identifying which that body message belongs to have to refer from the UDH itself, the last 5 UDH character. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, by using .str[:-1] in UDH column while selecting the last date of the received date/time.

```
groups = df.groupby([df['UDH'].str[:-1], 'Original Sender ID'])
df = groups.agg({'Body':''.join, 'Received Date/Time':max}).reset_index()
df = df.sort_values('Received Date/Time')
pd.options.display.width = 200
print(df.sort_values('Received Date/Time'))
```

Hope it helps the others out there who trying to implement the same thing